# In 1 Kings 19:2, could Jezebel have been putting a death hex on Elijah?

Tags: hebrew, elijah

In 1 Kings 19:2, the passage says:

2 Then Jezebel sent a messenger to Elijah, saying, “So let the gods do to me, and more also, if I do not make your life as the life of one of them by tomorrow about this time.” (NKJV)

וַתִּשְׁלַ֤ח אִיזֶ֙בֶל֙ מַלְאָ֔ךְ אֶל־אֵלִיָּ֖הוּ לֵאמֹ֑ר כֹּֽה־יַעֲשׂ֤וּן אֱלֹהִים֙ וְכֹ֣ה יֹוסִפ֔וּן
 כִּֽי־כָעֵ֤ת מָחָר֙ אָשִׂ֣ים אֶֽת־נַפְשְׁךָ֔ כְּנֶ֖פֶשׁ אַחַ֥ד מֵהֶֽם׃
(OT Westminster Leningrad Codex)

The passage is traditionally translated as though Jezebel was putting a curse on herself should she fail to kill Elijah.   This isn't logical, nor did it happen, for she lived many years.   Elijah however attempted suicide by going alone a day's journey into the desert.

The words 'to me' are added by translators and are not part of the original.  My view of this passage is that Jezebel put a death hex on Elijah so that if she failed to kill him, the gods would anyway.   Is this a valid interpretation?

Comment: I can't read the original text, but in 19:10 Elijah refers back to Jezebel trying to kill him. That might provide a hint.

Answer (score 1):

See Biblica: Robert J. Merecz, «[Jezebel’s Oath (1 Kgs 19,2)](https://www.bsw.org/biblica/vol-90-2009/jezebel-s-oath-1-kgs-19-2/19/)», Vol. 90 (2009) 257-259 for a detailed discussion of this subject.

After careful analysis of the text, Merecz concludes that Jezebel's goal was not to kill Elijah, but to frighten him into a hasty self-imposed exile. By running away, Elijah would leave his followers confused and undermine his victory at Mt. Carmel. Rather than sending an assassin, she cleverly sends him a dire-sounding warning which has the desired effect. Even her intimidating oath is subtly phrased so that she is not under the oath herself.

Comment: I dug up a [link](https://www.bsw.org/biblica/index-by-biblical-books/jezebel-s-oath-1-kgs-19-2/19/). @JohnVedder, could you expand your answer to  quote and explain the relevant parts of that work, while respecting its copyright?

Comment: I'll try, jpaugh, but feel free to expand further yourself. After careful analysis of the text, Merecz concludes that Jezebel's goal was not to kill Elijah, but to frighten him into a hasty self-imposed exile. By running away, Elijah would leave his followers confused and undermine his victory at Mt. Carmel. Rather than sending an assassin, she cleverly sends him a dire-sounding warning which has the desired effect. Even her intimidating oath is subtly phrased so that she is not under the oath herself.

Comment: Could you edit your points into your answer, where it will be most visible to future readers? Thanks. I read the whole text (but the link could disappear).  I'm hesitant to try to interpret your thoughts, since I'm both a layman and new to this particular [SE] community.

Comment: I'd suggest that interpreting my thoughts is quite unimportant.  What is important is summarizing Merecz's thoughts as given in his article. Perhaps you will give us your own understanding of this.

Comment: Your contribution is valuable and pertinent to the question, but by putting it in a comment instead of the answer, you loose the chance to gain "reputation" points, thereby gaining the [privileges](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) associated with that trust. If you decide to stay here, you'll find those privileges invaluable, especially the "comment everywhere" privilege. See the [tour] for more details.

Comment: @JohnVedder Regarding your comment: "I'd suggest that interpreting my thoughts is quite unimportant. What is important is summarizing Merecz's thoughts as given in his article." -- That's fine; a summary of Merecz's research as it pertains to this question is indeed a valuable addition, and you've demonstrated your ability to synthesize and summarize in the comment above. It doesn't "count" in comments, though, which (in this case) will be deleted, so I moved it into the answer. Feel free to [edit] further.